# javascript function returning issue

Tags: javascript, function

I want to return the var "source" value for all the element, now when I put the "source" out of each function, it become undefined.I want to return the whole source array. How to do that? any help would be truly appreciated -

```
function _getSource(){
    var product = fpd.getProduct(true);

    $(product[0].elements).each(function(i, elem) {
        var source = elem.parameters['source'];
    })

    return source;
    alert (source);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're actually after an *array* containing the `source` property of each element:

```
function _getSource(){
    var product = fpd.getProduct(true);

    return $(product[0].elements).map(function(i, elem) {
        return elem.parameters['source'];
    }).get();    // .get() turns jQuery collection into an array
}
```

`.map` is a very good replacement for a `.each` / `push` combo.  It comes from functional languages where the "map" function just takes an array, transmutes each elements, and returns a new array of those transmuted results.

The final `.get` is not strictly necessary if you don't mind getting an *array-like* result back rather than a proper array.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `var source` you are declaring a new variable scoped to the function of the `each` callback. Declare it outside and get rid of the `var` so you are just assigning instead of redeclaring, and you probably also want to build up an array and not just assign. Something like this:

```
function _getSource(){
    var product = fpd.getProduct(true);
    var sources = [];

    $(product[0].elements).each(function() {
        sources.push(elem.parameters['source']);
    })

    return sources;
}
```

Comment: he has no "outer source variable".  And why not use `.map` - it's designed for exactly this.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks, assumed there was an outer source. I agree that looping with `each` and calling `push` is not as elegant as `map`, but as the OP is admittedly beginner it may be better to take small steps

Answer (score 0):

`source` is only defined inside the `each` function because you `var`'d it there.

Try this instead:

```
function _getSource() {
    return $(fpd.getProduct(true)[0].elements).map(function() {return this.parameters['source'];});
}
```